# Suspend does not work on Lenovo v15-llL laptop running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: suspend, lenovo

When I suspend Ubuntu, a line appears on the monitor and does nothing

I use a Lenovo laptop

Nvidia corporation GP108M GeForce MX330

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Labtop model : lenovo v15-iiL

output cammand uname-a :

```
Linux ahmadreza-Lenovo-V15-IIL 5.11.0-41-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 10 10:20:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Which model of laptop? Is there a dedicated graphics card? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1378788/edit) the question.

Comment: The question has been edited

Comment: Please also add the exact model of the laptop (Lenovo has many laptop models). Also add the output of the command `uname -a` (copy paste the output in code form, don't post a screenshot of that).

Comment: The output was inserted